# I want to change a boolean variable based on other boolean variables for every observation in a Python data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, boolean-expression

A data summary looks like this from the data frame.  This just shows a subset where multiple A, B and C variables are True.  I only want one of them to be true.  I created the Multiples variable to select the ones to change and a summary looks like this table.

```
     A        B      C     Multiples
ID              
197 True    True    False   True
215 True    True    False   True
225 True    False   True    True
234 True    True    False   True
265 True    True    False   True
321 False   True    True    True
```

Here is an example of what the improved data would look like.   In every row only one of A, B or C is True and it's the rightmost one.  I need to know how make that change in Python.   Don't worry about the Multiples variable.   When I re-compute that, with A, B and C as they are below, all the Multiples will be False.   I already have the code to do that.

```
 A        B      C     Multiples
```

ID
197 False   True    False   False
215 False   True    False   False
225 False   False   True    False
234 False   True    False   False
265 False   True    False   False
321 False   False   True    False

I've searched the web and this site and can't find anything that works, at least that I understand.

Here is my current Python code:

```py
for index, item in enumerate(df['A']):
    if ((df['Multiples'] == True) & (df['C'] == True | df['B'] == True)):
        df['Multiples'] = False
```

Comment: If I understand you right, do you want the `Multiples` be `True` if only one of A, B and C is `True`?

Comment: No, guess I wasn't clear.  A, B and C are in the raw data.  Only one is supposed to be true.  If more than one is true it's dirty data and I need to fix it.  To find those conditions I created the Multiples variable which is true only if more than one of A, B or C is true.   Now that I've found them I need code to change either A or B to false.  I know the logical conditions to do that but don't know how to code it.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post there expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself with the following code:

```
def clear_redundant(row):
    # no need to change rows with only one True value
    if not row['Multiples']:
        return
    # if the last column is true, both earlier should be false
    if row['C']:
        row['A'] = False
        row['B'] = False
    # if the middle column is true, the first should be false
    elif row['B']:
        row['A'] = False

df.apply(clear_redundant, axis="columns")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `Multiples` as True if only one column is True:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  "A": [True, True,  True,  False],
  "B": [True, True,  False, False],
  "C": [True, False, False, False]
})

df['Multiples'] = 0+df['A']+df['B']+df['C'] == 1

print(df)
```

That will output:

```
       A      B      C  Multiples
0   True   True   True      False
1   True   True  False      False
2   True  False  False       True
3  False  False  False      False
```

To check for more than one True column use `> 1` instead of `== 1`.